# How rename each band of an Image Collection that I created in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I input each image and band and, created an Image Collection in GEE.
However, each band is as "b1" and I want to rename in order that I created the Image Collection
respectively as b1,b2,b3 and b4 .

I am trying as:

```
var mar_03 = ee.ImageCollection("users/nayaraestrabis/collection")
            .select(ee.Image("users/nayaraestrabis/collection/image_band2")).select('b1').rename('b2')
```

and it didn't work. I am trying to do a function, but I don't know how to do using an Image Collection.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working over an ImageCollection, you must use `map()` to iterate name changing over the entire collection. This is an example with Landsat scenes:

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LO08/C01/T1");

print(landsat.first().bandNames());

//["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B9","BQA"]

var changeNames = function(img){
  return img.select(['B1','B2','B3','B4'],['Band1','Band2','Band3','Band4']);
}

var landsatNewNames = landsat.map(changeNames);

print(landsatNewNames.first().bandNames());

//["Band1","Band2","Band3","Band4"]
```

I created `changeNames()` function for this purpose. Since this is an example, I only selected 4 bands changing names, consider selecting all bands needed

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your example helped me a lot =)
Obrigada!!